# How can identify dropdown list value in php and delete it in MySQLi when I click a button?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, drop-down-menu

I made a dropdown list. In the list there are the name of cars.
I would like to delete that car from MySQLi which has selected in the dropdown list.
For example I have four cars in the database: car_id, car_name. 1, Audi; 2,BMW; 3, Mazda; 4, Ferrari.

In the dropdown list appeared the four cars, and if I select BMW I would like to delete from the databse.

I made the dropdown list:

```
<?php
echo "<br/>";

$result = $db->query("SELECT car_id, car_name FROM cars");

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<select name='id'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        unset($id, $name);
        $id = $row['car_id'];
        $name = $row['car_name']; 
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
?>
```

The delete button form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="1"><input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The deleting code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM cars where car_name = '$name' ");
}
?>
```

The problem is that its delete the last value in the database, not that what I selected in the dropdown list.

Comment: Dropdown list __must be__ on the `<form>`

Comment: is the dropdown and the delete button in the same form?

Comment: This is how the code looks like. First the dropdown list (this is php) then under this the delete button form (this is html) and last one the deletion code(php). How can I change sequence to be good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the select inside a from and get the `id` of the car instead of name.

```
<?php
 //  get the id of the selected car.
if (isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM cars where car_id = '$id' ");
}
$result = $db->query("SELECT car_id, car_name FROM cars");
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
    <select name='id'>
        <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            unset($id, $name);
            $id = $row['car_id'];
            $name = $row['car_name'];
            echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $name . '</option>';
        }

        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete">
</form>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```